# Why doesn't git fetch update local branch?

Tags: git, git-fetch

I have the following scenario:

I have my remote branch equal to my local branch. Then I made some changes in the remote branch and some different changes in my local branch.

My idea is to run `git fetch`, to sync my local branch, then **check the differences**, and then push everything, but it simply doesn't work! (`git fetch` seems to not get the changes made in the remote branch before)
I know running `git pull` "fixes" this, or `git push -f` but I want to review the changes before commit.

Why doesn't `git fetch` work as expected? Or how can I otherwise review the differences before commit?

Comment: @SurajRao well, my question was more about why in this scenario didn't work as expected, more than the differences between this 2 commands

Comment: Well, I don't agree that it's a dup of that question because it isn't what was actually asked, but it is true that if you *really* understand the difference between pull and fetch, then your expectation would be different and you wouldn't think that the fetch hadn't worked as expected.

Comment: `git fetch` does not obtain *changes* (and in fact branches don't *hold* changes). What `git fetch` obtains are *commits* (and each branch name, or any other name in Git, simply points to *one specific commit*).

Answer (score 2):

`git fetch` downloads commits from the remote branch, but doesn't update your workspace. You won't see the commits until they are merged into your local branch.

`git pull` is a combination of `git fetch` and `git merge` - this is why `git pull` appears to "fix" this behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

To view the differences between your local branch and the remote branch before merging them, you can use `git diff`, as outlined in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1800783/compare-local-git-branch-with-remote-branch), after executing `git fetch`.

If you want to execute the merge of your remote branch with your local branch without committing it immediately to allow you to review the result, you can use `git pull --no-commit` (as described [on git-scm.com](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull)). The `--no-commit` option prevents Git from automatically committing a merge that may be part of the pull, which would allow you to review the merge result before committing it.