# Git unable to access diff

Tags: git, github, git-diff

I'm trying to make a diff but using

```
git diff KDE/krita  mrmajik45/krita
```

Says that it can't access KDE/krita. Please help.

( not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git)
for Eft.
(error: Could not access 'KDE/krita')
I'm trying to compare my fork to Master.

Comment: well... the basics. Can you post the exact error message? Do you have a branch called KDE/krita? This will help us figure it out: `git branch -a | grep KDE/krita`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to compare your own fork master branch to the original ("upstream") repository is:

```
git clone https://github.com/mrmajik45/krita
cd krita
git remote add upstream https://github.com/KDE/krita
git fetch upstream
```

Then you can do, still in the krita folder; a diff [between your local an remote upstream-repo branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1801150/6309):

```
git diff master upstream/master
```

Comment: I'll try this brb.

Comment: How do i get a raw diff file from it?

Comment: @Mrmajik45 https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#git-diff---raw: `git diff --raw`. You had selected the right answer.