# Empty merge conflicts

Tags: git, git-pull

Sometimes, when I do `git pull origin master` from a local branch, I get merge conflicts like:

```
<<<<<<HEAD

======

>>>>>>xxxxxx
```

How to avoid that ? Maybe it is due to some white spaces, so I tried to put a `.gitattributes` file containing `* -whitespace` but that didn't solve the problem.

Comment: What does git diff say? Perhaps a windows liunx linebreak issue?

Comment: @Christoph I'm not a star with `git`. What shoud i type exactly ? Just `git diff`, from my local branch, and this compares to the remote branch `master` ?

Comment: Will try that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1800783/how-to-compare-a-local-git-branch-with-its-remote-branch

Comment: I don’t think you need to be a star at git. It’s likely that you’ve got invisible characters causing an issue.

Comment: Instead of doing `git pull origin master`, I've just done `git fetch` followed by `git merge -s recursive -Xignore-space-change origin/master`. This worked and I got no confict this time.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent consider adding that as an answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this case, you have white-space differences.  Git considers whitespace differences significant.  (If this were not the case, well ... imagine maintaining a program written in [Whitespace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_(programming_language)), for instance.)

Your comment:

> ... followed by `git merge -s recursive -Xignore-space-change origin/master`. This worked and I got no confict this time.

confirms that the conflicts were merely with whitespace.  The `-X` argument—I call these *extended arguments*, with `X` standing for *eXtended*)—`ignore-space-change` tells Git that, during the merge, if your change and their change are the same except for whitespace, this is not really a conflict.

The precise rules for these four extended options are described in [the documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge):

> `ignore-space-change`
>   `ignore-all-space`
>   `ignore-space-at-eol`
>   `ignore-cr-at-eol`
>
> Treats lines with the indicated type of whitespace change as
>   unchanged for the sake of a three-way merge. Whitespace changes
>   mixed with other changes to a line are not ignored. See also
>   [git-diff[1]](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff) `-b`, `-w`, `--ignore-space-at-eol`, and
>   `--ignore-cr-at-eol`.
>
> - If **their** version only introduces whitespace changes to a
>     line, our version is used;
> - If **our** version introduces whitespace changes but **their**
>     version includes a substantial change, **their** version is
>     used;
> - Otherwise, the merge proceeds in the usual way.

Note that you can usually spell this command more simply as:

```
git merge -X ignore-space-change
```

The `-s recursive` is the default, and `origin/master` is presumably already set as the upstream of your current branch `master` so that this too is the default.

(The space between `-X` and its argument is optional, but I prefer to use it.)

Comment: Thanks. Nothing happens if I simply do `git merge -X ignore-space-change`. This only prints "Already up-to-date". I have to do `git merge -X ignore-space-change origin/master`.

Comment: That implies that the upstream is *not* `origin/master`, but rather something else. If you like that arrangement, all you can leave out is the `-s recursive` part. (That the current branch's upstream is not `origin/master` implies in turn that the current branch is probably not `master`: I was assuming that it was. You only said "a local branch", not *which* local branch, so that last assumption on my part was probably wrong.)