# How to compare local and remote branch trees in git?

Tags: git, command, diff

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1800787/2989289) describes how to get the (file) difference between two branches.

I was was wonder how to know how much commits my *local* branch diff from *remote* one.

I mean, number of commits *ahead*, *beside* or *behind*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compare two random branches `A` and `B`, to find how many commits on `A` are new to `B`:

```
git rev-list --count B..A
```

`A` and `B` could have one of these relationships:

1. `A` and `B` are unrelated branches;
2. `A` is up-to-date with `B`;
3. `A` is ahead of `B`;
4. `A` is behind `B`;
5. `A` is diverged with `B`.

To find out which relationship it is with `foo.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

A=$1
B=$2

merge_base=$(git merge-base $A $B)
if [[ "${merge_base}" = "" ]];then
    echo "$A and $B are unrelated"
else
    num_new_to_A=$(git rev-list --count $A..$B)
    num_new_to_B=$(git rev-list --count $B..$A)
    if [[ "${num_new_to_A}" -eq 0 ]] && [[ "${num_new_to_B}" -eq 0 ]];then
        echo "$A is up-to-date with $B"
    elif [[ "${num_new_to_A}" -eq 0 ]] && [[ "${num_new_to_B}" -gt 0 ]];then
        echo "$A is ${num_new_to_B} commits ahead of $B"
    elif [[ "${num_new_to_A}" -gt 0 ]] && [[ "${num_new_to_B}" -eq 0 ]];then
        echo "$A is ${num_new_to_A} commits behind $B"
    elif [[ "${num_new_to_A}" -gt 0 ]] && [[ "${num_new_to_B}" -gt 0 ]];then
        echo "$A is diverged with $B, ${num_new_to_B} commits ahead and ${num_new_to_A} commits behind"
    else
        :
    fi
fi
```

To compare `master` and `origin/master`:

```
bash foo.sh master origin/master
```

Comment: You can get both counts in one `git rev-list` using `git rev-list --count --left-right $A...$B` (note three dots), which outputs the two individual counts in the order of "only on $A" then "only on $B". You'll still need the initial "are these related" test though.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`@{u}` upstream or `@{push}` gitrevisions syntax](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions#Documentation/gitrevisions.txt-em-ltngtemegem-1em) to count the number of commits:

- ahead: `git rev-list --count ..@{u}`
- behind: `git rev-list --count @{u}..`

Answer (score 1):

You may just type `git status` from the Git bash to get this information.  Git will compare your current local branch against its remote tracking counterpart.  You will see something like this:

```
$ git status
# On branch master
```

This will be followed by a status message such as the following:

```
# Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'
# Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commit.
# Your branch is behind 'origin/master' by 1 commit.
# Your branch is 1 commit ahead and 2 commits behind 'origin/master'
```

The first message means that your local branch is completely current with the remote tracking branch.  The second and third messages mean that either your branch has an extra commit versus the remote, or vice-versa.  The fourth message would be shown if both your local branch and the remote branch had new commits since the point where your branched off.