# Why does git fetch not seem to actually fetch the latest remote commits?

Tags: git

So, this has been asked elsewhere, but the answers I see don't seem to work for me.

I have a bare remote repository, "origin". I work locally, in a branch named "ect010", which the remote has as well, and it is tracked:

```
git remote show origin
* remote origin
  Fetch URL: /projects/ECT/bareChain.git
  Push  URL: /projects/ECT/bareChain.git
  HEAD branch: master
  Remote branches:
    develop tracked
    ect010  tracked
    master  tracked
    oldXML  tracked
  Local branch configured for 'git pull':
    ect010 merges with remote ect010
  Local ref configured for 'git push':
    ect010 pushes to ect010 (local out of date)
```

The remote ect010 branch has a few more recent commits than my local ect010 (I can see these commit if I go tho the bare directory and do a git log).

Knowing this, I do from my local ect010 branch:

```
git fetch origin ect010
```

Which doesn't seem to do much:

```
From /projects/ECT/bareChain
 * branch            ect010     -> FETCH_HEAD
```

..and finally, I want to see the differences between my local ect010 and the remote ect010, so I tried

```
git log origin/ect010
```

**But this shows the same log as my local log, not showing the latest commits that I know are pushed on bare.** Why? Obviously I am doing something wrong, but as I see on some [other posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1800783/how-to-compare-a-local-git-branch-with-its-remote-branch), this technique should work.. no?

I'd appreciate any help!
Thanks a lot,

Arnaud

**EDIT:** (because I also see this suggestion in other answers, but seems OK in my config)

Doing

```
git config --get remote.origin.fetch
```

Gives:

```
+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

..which seems OK, right?

Comment: You must have a very old version of Git. The default behavior for `git fetch origin <name>` changed in Git 1.8.2 to update `origin/<name>`. Current Git is 2.26; 1.7 and 1.8 were outdated many years ago. That said, just run `git  fetch`, as in the accepted answer.

Comment: True.. I am using 1.7.1 ! Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you do `git fetch origin ect010` it fetches the branch into a special ref called `FETCH_HEAD`, it does not update the `remotes/origin/*` branches. And you see it tells you so:

```
From /projects/ECT/bareChain
 * branch            ect010     -> FETCH_HEAD
```

Just do `git fetch origin` so it will do fetches according to `+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*` pattern.

BTW, if you want just to fetch that single branch, you have to specify full names and `:` for the mapping, according to the pattern above. I.e.

```
git fetch origin refs/heads/ect010:refs/remotes/origin/ect010
```

But honestly I don't see any reason why would you ever need this. Just fetch everything.