# Git local branch is not up to date with remote

Tags: git, github, version-control

I've looked through 4-5 other threads about this, but haven't been able to pinpoint where I went wrong. here's the issue:

I have a remote branch, **`in-progress-show-hide-countries`**.

I logged into another PC that doesn't have the remote branch tracked yet.
I run something, probably `git pull`, and it fetches some things, but my memory gets fuzzy around here. I notice that my local files don't have the changes that remote has.

Here are some of the things I've tried:

```
$ git status
On branch in-progress-show-hide-countries
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/in-progress-show-hide-countries'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

git diff shows no code differences, but the changes are definitely visible on my github.

```
$ git diff in-progress-show-hide-countries...origin/in-progress-show-hide-countries
```

Git log shows that I'm.. probably?? tracking the remote branch

```
$ git log
commit 4624760c5d66df430fc3d91fc718ffd04f27e292 (HEAD -> in-progress-show-hide-countries, origin/in-progress-show-hide-countries, main)
```

But maybe I don't know what I'm saying, so here's my git remote -v

```
$ git remote -v
origin  git@github.com:XXX/fullstackopen.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:XXX/fullstackopen.git (push)
```

This thread ( [How to compare a local Git branch with its remote branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1800783/how-to-compare-a-local-git-branch-with-its-remote-branch) ) suggests that I can use `git diff <local branch> <remote>/<remote branch>` to see what the difference between my local and the remote branch looks like, so I try:

Empty output

```
$ git diff in-progress-show-hide-countries origin/in-progress-show-hide-countries
```

Any clues? I realize I can just delete everything locally and re-clone, but that wouldn't help my learning very much. Appreciate any advice.

Answer (score 1):

The trick—well, okay, one of many tricks—with Git is to realize that *branches* don't *mean* anything.  You use branch names in your Git to keep track of *commits*.  It's not the branches that matter, it's the commits.

Those SHA IDs, `4624760c5d6...`, are what matter.  Those are what Git *needs*.  You can have any number of names *attached to* any one of these:

> ```
> commit 4624760c5d66df430fc3d91fc718ffd04f27e292
> (HEAD -> in-progress-show-hide-countries,
> origin/in-progress-show-hide-countries, main)
> ```

This shows that there are three names for `46247...`, namely `in-progress-show-hide-countries`, `origin/origin/in-progress-show-hide-countries`, and `main`.  The special name `HEAD` is "attached to" the name `in-progress-show-hide-countries`, meaning `in-progress-show-hide-countries` is your current *branch name*.

The use of a branch name allows you to avoid typing in `4624760c5d66df430fc3d91fc718ffd04f27e292` every time.  (I can't type that in correctly every time: I used cut-and-paste with the mouse.  I have enough trouble with `in-progress-show-hide-countries`, which I also cut-and-paste.)  Besides that, by selecting a name like `main` or `in-progress-show-hide-countries` as your *current* name, you arrange for Git to update the hash ID stored *in* the name whenever you make a *new commit*.  So your name always remembers the *latest* commit.  A nice, short, easy to type, easy to remember name, like `main` or `wip-shc` for work-in-progress on show-hide-countries, is a good idea ... **for you**.  Git doesn't care about the *names;* Git cares about the *hash IDs*.

Commits themselves *also* remember commit hash IDs for you.  So whenever you make a *new* commit, the new commit remembers, for you, which commit was the current commit at that time.  Make a *second* new commit, and the new commit remembers the *first* new commit.

If we replace each commit hash ID with a simple uppercase letter:

```
... <-F <-G <-H   <-- wip-shc (HEAD), main
```

we can see how attaching `HEAD` to and making new commits work.  Remembering that commits always point *backwards* like this, we make a new commit `I`, whose parent is the current commit `H`:

```
... <-F <-G <-H   <-- main
               \
                I   <-- wip-shc (HEAD)
```

The name `main` did not move, but because we were "on" branch `wip-shc`, the name `wip-shc` *did* move.  Make another new commit `J` and we get:

```
... <-F <-G <-H   <-- main
               \
                I <-J   <-- wip-shc (HEAD)
```

The *name* always picks the *last* commit, from which Git works backwards.  There are now two ways to get to commit `H`, in this drawing (and three ways to get there in your existing repository) but all we need is *some* way, *any* way, to get there in order to find it.  Git will *automatically work backwards* when it needs to.  You just have to supply it the starting hash ID—for which you use a branch name like `wip-shc` or `main`, or a *remote-tracking name* like `origin/in-progress-show-hide-countries`.

Your Git will automatically create or update the *remote-tracking names*—the `origin/in-progress-show-hide-countries` style names—when your Git reaches out to their repository, over at `origin`,<sup>1</sup> and has them list out *their* branch names.  If they have `in-progress-show-hide-countries` pointing to commit `H`, your Git creates or updates your `origin/in-progress-show-hide-countries` to point to commit `H`.

If your name `wip-shc` points to the *same* commit as their name `in-progress-show-hide-countries` which is your `origin/in-progress-show-hide-countries`, those two names are synchronized with each other, and you are "up to date".  That's all this means.

---

<sup>1</sup>Confusingly, Git calls `origin` a *remote*, and `origin/main` and the like are thus *remote-tracking branch names*.  They're not actually *branch* names once they're in your repository though.  So I drop the word *branch* and call them *remote-tracking names*.  More confusingly, Git uses the word *track* in at least two or three different ways.  A branch can "track" a *remote-tracking [branch] name*, and files are either "tracked" or "untracked", and every one of these mean something different.

---

#### What about when your files don't match

The files you can see and work on / with, in any clone of any repository, are *not in the repository*.  The files that *are* in the repository are stored in a special, read-only, Git-only, compressed and de-duplicated form, that only Git can read and literally nothing—not even Git itself—can overwrite.  These files are entirely useless for getting any new work done.  So these files *are not used* for getting new work done.

Instead, when you select some commit to work on—with `git checkout` or `git switch`, usually—you're directing Git to *copy the files out of that commit*.  The files come out of the commit and are de-compressed back to useful form (causing duplication, if they have duplicates).  The expanded-out files go in your *working tree* (sometimes shortened to work-tree).  These files are not *in* Git, even if they came *out of* Git.

As you work on those files, *nothing happens inside Git*.  Those files aren't in Git, so changing them—or adding new files, or removing files; you can do whatever you want here—has no effect *on* Git.

At some point, though, you presumably want to use these updated files to *make a new commit*.  To do that, you must use `git add`<sup>2</sup> followed by `git commit`.  That makes the new commit, which then updates your current branch name.

Note that your branch names are *yours*.  They are not in any other Git repository.  If you let someone clone your Git repository, your branch names become someone else's remote-tracking names (so now they can *see* your branch names), but they're still your *branch* names, which aren't someone else's branch names.  Someone else's branch names are probably your remote-tracking names.

Once you make a new *commit*, you may or may not be using similar branch names, but now they won't be in sync.  You synchronize by sending your new commit to them, and that's where `git push` would come in.

---

<sup>2</sup>You can sometimes get away with `git commit -a` to avoid the `git add` step.  But doing this to avoid learning about Git's index is a bad idea: Git will eventually whack you over the head with its index, forcing you to learn about it.  Learn about it before it's an emergency.  Git is a pain sometimes, yes.

---

#### Names do not have to match

There *are* good reasons to use the same name on both "sides", as it were: it becomes pretty crazy to try to remember, e.g., *my xyzzy is Fred's plugh, but René uses the name vue and Sasha calls it супеp*.  If everyone uses the same name, your `origin/main` and your `main` at least have the same *purpose*, even if the hash IDs get de-synchronized.  But in some cases that's literally impossible: you might have two people you work with who both call their (different) branches `tall`, and hence two *remotes* `batman` and `robin` and you can't necessarily just *one* branch name on your side called `tall`, so you end up with `tall-batman` and `tall-robin`, or whatever.

When you use `git fetch`, the names don't have to match, because your Git is going to create or update *remote-tracking names*.  You'll have `origin/whatever` for their branch `whatever`.  You can use any name you like on your side.

When you use `git push` to *send* commits *to* `origin`, though, you have to end your `git push` with a request that they set one of *their branch names*.  If you have branch names that *don't* match, like the `batman` and `robin` case, you do this with, e.g.:

```
git push robin robin-tall:tall
```

Here you write *your* branch name on the left side of the colon `:`, and *their* branch name on the right.  (The `robin` in the middle here is the *remote:* a short name for the URL where you're sending the commits; this is the same name you use with `git fetch robin`, and that is where names like `robin/tall` comes from: your Git pastes the remote name in front of their branch name.<sup>3</sup>)  If your branch names *do* match up, though, a simple:

```
git push origin somebranch
```

suffices: this means *use the same name on both sides*, i.e., send them my latest `somebranch` commit(s) and then ask them to incorporate those commits into *their* branch named `somebranch`.

They may *refuse* to update their branch.  In this case, we get into more complexities: we have to find out *why* they refused and figure out what to do about that.  But this, so far, is the simple part of `git push`.  It means *send them my new commits that they don't have yet, then ask them to set one of their branch names*.  You must pick the commits to send—that's from the left side of the colon—and the name, from the right side.  If you use the same name on *both* sides, you get to leave out the colon and type less.

---

<sup>3</sup>It's actually quite a bit more complicated internally—this is a Git tradition after all, nothing can be as simple as it looks—but that's the end effect.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the thorough explanation. This will take me some time to digest, but it's very enlightening. If I'm not mistaken, the takeaway message here is that "Your branch is up to date with 'origin/in-progress-show-hide-countries'." does not mean that my local changes reflect the latest commits: what matters is that I am working on the same commit as the remote commit hash (and this ensures that I am working on the codebase that I want to be working on, assuming that HEAD is also pointed to that specific hash). Does it sound like I have a better understanding?

Comment: Yes - you may have different checked-out files, but you're starting from the same starting-point, i.e., the same commit hash ID.

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure that you are on the correct branch, which you can change using:

```
git checkout -b in-progress-show-hide-countries
```

If you have no *real* changes on your system, you can just use

```
git reset HEAD --hard
```

which will set you back to the most recent commit on the Github repository. **Do not use lightly!** The work that is reset can't be recovered.

Comment: Doing this returned "HEAD is now at 4624760". This is the SHA of the commit on the remote where I want to pull changes from. However, the changes aren't shown locally. After this command, I tried git fetch (no response), and git status (On branch in-progress-show-hide-countries
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/in-progress-show-hide-countries'.). Did I skip a step?