# Is there a way to preview changes made by cherry-picking multiple commits in Git before pushing them?

Tags: git

Is there any way to see the changes from the `cherry-pick`?, I was trying `cherry-pick`

```
git cherry-pick commit-hash-1 commit-hash-2
```

for multiple commits and i got multiple conflicts which i have resolved, but unable to check the difference before pushing it.

I can see the changes once i pushed and check difference between the branches, but i want to see the difference before pushing from the local.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1801150/7034621) where `<origin>/<remote_branch>` would refer to base of the branch you're intending to merge your changes to?

Comment: Don't forget to give a feedback otherwise nobody will be motivated to answer you again. Welcome to Stackoverflow!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see changes in your local branch that are committed but not pushed yet into remote you could use (note that `origin` is your remote's name):

```
git diff origin...
```

But more interesting is to see changes both committed and not (the working tree), that way you could check your work without even committing and fix any problems you find in the code. Note that you can see changes in files added to git only:

```
git diff-index -p --merge-base origin
```

To see changes in staged files only you should add `--cached`:

```
 git diff-index -p --cached --merge-base origin
```